# Using KeyEvents and Mouse events at the same time

Tags: java, applet, mouseevent, keyboard-events

I'm trying to create a simple Java applet that can detect both the location of the mouse within the applet and detect whether the shift key has been released or pressed. When I add a KeyListener, though, the program ignores the mouseMove event. How can I get the mouseMove event to work while also using KeyListener?

```
public class Test extends java.applet.Applet implements java.awt.event.KeyListener {
    String message;
    int moveX, moveY;

    public Test() { this.addKeyListener(this); }

    public void init() {
        message = "";
        moveX = moveY = 0;
    }

    public void paint(java.awt.Graphics g) {
        new Test();
        g.drawString(message,15,15);
        g.drawString("(" + moveX + "," + moveY + ")",900,630);
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getKeyCode() == java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT)
            message = "Shift key pressed";
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent e) {
        message = "Shift key released";
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent e) {}

    public boolean mouseMove(java.awt.Event e, int x, int y) {
        moveX = x;
        moveY = y;
        repaint();
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: You've only implemented a keylistener

Comment: But it performs an action, right? If the shift key is pressed, the display changes.

Comment: `KeyListener` will only raise events if the component it is registered to is focusable and has keyboard focus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by replacing `mouseMove(java.awt.Event e, int x, int y)` with `mouseMoved(java.awt.event.MouseEvent e)`, so now the coordinates change when the mouse's location changes and the message changes when the shift key is held down.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check if someone was holding shift or another key while clicking, MouseEvent has a method called `getModifiers()`